# Python 3.6.5 returns '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'str' error message

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, tuples, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to split a data set into a training and testing part. I am struggling at a structural problem as it seems as the hierarchy of the data seems to be wrong to proceed with below code.

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader('SPY', data_source='morningstar')['Close'])
cutoff = '2015-1-1'
data = data[data.index < cutoff].dropna().copy()
```

Comment: Most likely `data.index` is not a `pd.DatetimeIndex` and you need to preprocess it to put it in a useful form.

Comment: So what does 'web.DataReader()` return in this case? You appear to have a compound index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `data.head()` will reveal, `data` is not actually a `pd.DataFrame` but a `pd.Series` whose index is a `pd.MultiIndex` (as suggested also by the error which hints that each element is a tuple) rather than a `pd.DatetimeIndex`.

What you could do would be to simply let

```
df = data.unstack(0)
```

With that, `df[df.index < cutoff]` performs the filtering you are trying to do.

Comment: Many thanks! You are right, I didnt check if the data frame object was actually a data frame. I am pretty sure it used to work before seamlessly